# Include setting lines into apache .conf file

Tags: apache, configuration

I want to add some lines with something like an `include` into a `.conf` file. For example, my SSL settings for then include this some lines into each `<VirtualHost>` like this:

```
<VirtualHost>
  Include "path/myfile.txt"
</VirtualHost>
```

And in 'myfile.txt' I want to include some settings like:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ...
```

**An from my `.conf` file, call that other file to include their content.**

**Is it possible?** I didn't saw something like this in web. Any hint?

Comment: With includes you should include the entire directive including the <VirtualHost> directive.

Comment: Ok. You mean that I cannot do what I want? Thank for quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

By default on Apache 2.4 you should get separate conf files for Non SSL and SSL VirtualHosts.

So it's better to manage them that way IMO opinion and keep the files separate. So in your primary httpd.conf file you can include the two files.

```
httpd-ssl.conf
httpd-vhosts.conf
```

You would include those in your httpd.conf or apache.conf file depdending on distro.

httpd-ssl.conf will contain all your SSL settings and your SSL sites Listening on port 443.

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCipherSuite ...
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SiteInfo here
</VirtualHost>
```

httpd-vhosts.conf will contain all your non ssl sites Listening on port 80

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  SiteInfo here
</VirtualHost>
```

Then you can put this at the bottom of your apache config file.

```
Include /path/to/httpd-vhosts.conf
Include /path/to/httpd-ssl.conf
```

Comment: Thanks for good explanation but the solution is that there isn't solution for include parts of directive like modular form.
Thanks anyway @PanamaJack!